# How to write unit test cases for kafkajs consumer and producer

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, kafkajs

I'm new to kafkajs and I want to write unit test cases for the Kafka consumer and producer. Currently my project uses Typescript, Chai and Mocha as test framework.